# Cannot load relative src Images on any browser in Linux

Tags: javascript, linux, image, relative-path

I have tried the same code on multiple Linux distributions but the same issue occurs. Whenever I try to load the following line, every browser on Linux that I've tried reports "Couldn't load image":

`<img src = 'Images/image.png'>`

On Windows, the exact same file with this line of code works perfectly. VSCode detects the file path of the image and I can click into it from the editor so I'm pretty sure that the address is correct.

I have tried:

- Different browsers
- Loading the same file on Ubuntu and Fedora
- Addressing the file with a full path

Each time, the same thing happens where it shows me the broken image icon. I'm not sure what to do from here. I'd appreciate any info on the matter. Thank you!